# ORA-01008: not all variables bound ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721. I am learning SQL and I got this error

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a simple table with one PRIMARY Key column and two VARCHAR columns

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    fName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    lName VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO student VALUES(1, "Rahul", "Krub");
INSERT INTO VALUES(&student_id, &fName, &lName);
SELECT * FROM student;
```

I have no idea why the latter is not working while the former does? **I want to dynamically enter data into the table** (User Inputted). Please help me out I cannot find the answer for this anywhere as all of my searches keep leading me to dynamic SQL.

Comment: Which client/IDE are you running this in, and how? (Your first insert won't work either because you have double-quotes around the string literals, so those will be reported as invalid identifiers or column references; and the second should have (single) quotes around the second and third substitution variables - that isn't causing the error though; and the table name...)

Comment: @AlexPoole I use the https://livesql.oracle.com/ Live SQL worksheet by Oracle

Comment: Actually, your first INSERT should not work, either.  Enclosing Rahul and Krub in double-quotes causes oracle to treat them as case-sensitive object names, not string values.  They should be enclosed in single quotes to treat them as a string.

Comment: [From the Live SQL FAQ](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:39::::::#FAQ): "... we do not support input parameters at runtime."